# Makedirs error unexpected keyword argument 'exists_ok'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use python to create a new folder and if that folder already exists not giving me an exception. Hence I am running the code:

```
import os 

os.makedirs('test', exist_ok=True)
```

I am then getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\testing.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.makedirs('test', exist_ok=True)  
TypeError: makedirs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exist_ok'
```

I don't really understand what this means or why its not working?

I cannot really find that much documentation on exist_ok other than it is new to python 3.2 below

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=makedirs#os.makedirs

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are running your script using Python 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, I'm using python 3.4

you can check your version from the command line using python3 --version or python --version .

From your script you can check it with the following code:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Comment: Sorry about my late reply, I am using Python 3.5. I am using LiClipse, but when I tried the same code in the command line of my install of Idle it seemed to work?